# I am trying to extract a substring using regex_replace command . I want to extract "SWIFTInward" here

Tags: python, powershell, shell, azure-devops, character-encoding

- hosts: windows
- strategy: linear
- vars:

  war_file_path: `F:\\Install\\IIBProjects\\DE\\WAR\\DE_SWIFTInward-202010.0.0.war`
- tasks:
- name: Get properties folder path for windows
- set_fact:it
  it

```
        endpointDetails: "{{ item | win_basename | regex_replace('\\\\(?:(?!\\\\).)*$', '') }}"
      with_items:
        "{{ war_file_path }}"
      register: war_file_name
      when: ansible_os_family == "Windows"
```

- **Expected output:** `SWIFTInward`
- **Error output which i am getting**: `DE_SWIFTInward-202010.0.0.war`

I want to get "SWIFTInward" as output but i am getting the whole base name . could anyone help please

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: I tried {{ item | win_basename | regex_replace('\\\\(?:(?!\\\\).)*$', '') }} through set_facts in  asnible